# Central background image width element padding

Tags: css, background-image, padding

I have some td elements (`.nav_item`) in table. Also I have one active td with class `.nav_item` and id `#nav_item_active`, which background has a little white triangle on the bottom. That triangle should be in the center of td, but it is a bit right because of right padding of element. Can I solve my problem with css? I want to use `padding-right: 30px;` and center the image. Is it possible?

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vUPdq/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is not affected by the padding. The background appears to not be centered because the text is set to `text-align:left;`.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/kU6fu/

Set the background-position to `center bottom`, center the text, and keep the padding even on both right and left sides.

Comment: I can't possibly understand why/why not. In any case, you can manually adjust background position like `background-position: 10px 30px;`